# OpenGL: How to check if the user supports glGenBuffers()?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, opengl

I checked docs, and it says OpenGL version must be at least 1.5 to make `glGenBuffers()` work. The user has version 1.5 but the function call will cause a crash. Is this a mistake in the docs, or a driver problem on the user?

I am using this `glGenBuffers()` for VBO, how do i check if the user has support for this?

**Edit:** im using glew with `glewInit()` to initialize VBO

**Edit2:** I got it working on the user with `glGenBuffersARB()` function calls. But im still looking a way to find out when should i use `glGenBuffers()` and when should i use `glGenBuffersARB()` AND when should i use VertexArrays if none of the VBO function calls are supported.

I also found out that `if(GLEW_VERSION_1_5)` returns false on the user, but `GL_VERSION` gives 1.5.0, which just doesnt make any sense!

Comment: Did you verify that you have a valid OpenGL context before the call?

Comment: I have no clue what is that and where is it checked.

Comment: If you don't use a VBO, rendering in OpenGL works fine?

Comment: Yes, theres no other problem than VBO on some users.

Comment: When do you make your call to glGenBuffers()? Immediately after your call to glewInit() or later on?

Comment: later, does the delay really matter?

Comment: No, I was just thinking that an early call might cause a problem. But that's not it then. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to tell you now to stay far away from GLEW or any of these libraries mostly because they're useless, this is how I have always done it.

```
#ifndef STRINGIFY
  #define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#endif
#ifdef WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
  #define glGetProcAddress(a) wglGetProcAddress(a)
#endif
#ifdef X11
  #define glGetProcAddress(a) glXGetProcAddress ( \
    reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(a)     \
  )
#endif

#ifndef GetExtension
  #define GetExtension(Type, ExtenName)     \
    ExtenName = (Type)                      \
    glGetProcAddress(STRINGIFY(ExtenName)); \
    if(!ExtenName)                          \
    {                                       \
      std:cout << "Your Computer Does Not " \
               << "Support GL Extension: "  \
               << STRINGIFY(ExtenName)      \
               << std::endl;                \
      exit(1);                              \         
    }                                       \
    else                                    \
    {                                       \
      std::cout << "Loadded Extension: "    \
                << STRINGIFY(ExtenName)     \
                << std::endl;               \
    }
#endif

// then just use this :D
GetExtension(PFNGLGENBUFFERSARBPROC, glGenBuffersARB)
// after your done you can do this
#undef GetExtension
#undef glGetProcAddress
// you can then also undef the STRINGIFY macro
// though it does come in handy.
```

Comment: do note that X11 is where X.ORG is used, like on linux, and unix like OS's, there is also a MacOSX way to do the GetExtension too, I just cannot remember it.

Comment: is it possible to do this without using a macro?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://glew.sourceforge.net/basic.html). Maybe it will help you;)

```
if (GLEW_VERSION_1_5)
{
  /* You have OpenGL 1.5 */
}
```

Try glGenBuffersARB insted glGenBuffers; I think you only need to check 1.5 support;

Comment: Can you tell the correct extension name for using VBO? OR give some list where i can find these things

Comment: Do i have to convert all the other function calls to *ARB as well? Like glBindBuffer() and glBufferData() etc.

Comment: "GLEW doesn't automatically remap glGenBuffers to glGenBuffersARB" http://old.nabble.com/glGenBuffers-crash-td26618791.html

Comment: What is the point of using glGenBuffers() at all then? Or do i have to use glGenBuffers() for some users, and glGenBuffersARB() for other users? Surprisingly, both works on my computer o_O

Comment: As i know glGenBuffersARB works only via extensions, but glGenBuffers works directly on all OpenGL 1.5 systems.

Comment: And as about extensions, you can check your card by calling glGetString with GL_EXTENSIONS parameter.

Comment: Yes, but which extension i check?

Comment: Check GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object

Comment: checking with `if(GLEW_VERSION_1_5)` didnt work, the user got a false from that. And the user supports VBO after all, seems like glGenBuffersARB() did the trick (also replaced all other functions to *ARB).

Comment: The GLEW_VERSION_1_5 check is really odd, because the GL_VERSION string returns 1.5.0 for the user, how its possible GLEW_VERSION_1_5 returns false?

Comment: @Newbie what is the main question?)))