# "First-chance exception at 0x00000000" What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, glut

This is my code so far, it's just tutorial code from open.gl

```
#include <GL/GL.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>    
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <thread>
#define GLEW_STATIC

int main(){
    //printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS))
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;

    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 2);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr); // Windowed
    //GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(1920, 1080, "OpenGL", glfwGetPrimaryMonitor(), nullptr); fs

    //typedef void (*GENBUFFERS) (GLsizei, GLuint*);
    //GENBUFFERS glGenBuffers = (GENBUFFERS)glfwGetProcAddress("glGenBuffers");

    printf("%s\n", glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS));

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glewInit();


    GLuint vertexBuffer;

    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    printf("%u\n", vertexBuffer);

    float vertices[] = {
     0.0f,  0.5f, // Vertex 1 (X, Y)
     0.5f, -0.5f, // Vertex 2 (X, Y)
    -0.5f, -0.5f  // Vertex 3 (X, Y)
    };


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);


    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);



    //glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_FALSE);


    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
    }


    glfwTerminate();
}
```

returns the exception above... what is going on and what's wrong?

the error drops at `glGenBuffers(1,&vertexBuffer);`

I'm still very new to opengl programming so please break it down into autismally small pieces for me if you can :)

Comment: `glGenBuffers(1,&buffer)` does not exist in the code you have showed us. So now I wonder what else doesn't match up? Please take more care when forming questions.

Comment: This means you are trying to access a null pointer. Although it appears you changed your code from what you are asking since glGenBuffers(1,&buffer) does not exist.

Comment: It was just a different name for the reference, I was using a different name, I don't appreciate the snide careless remarks. check for the method instead of a name next time :)

Answer (score 1):

An error occurring at location 0 suggests you're trying to call a function using a null function pointer. The culprit in your case seems to be `glGenBuffers`. It's been in the core for a long time, so it's almost certainly supported by your machine. It probably just hasn't been initialised properly.

You can get libraries such as GLEW (GL Extension Wrangler) to help you with that. It's not something you should rely on long-term, but can definitely help you get started without worrying about lots of details.

Alternatively, a very quick-and-dirty solution may be just to call `glGenBuffersARB()` instead. Again, that's definitely not something to rely on long-term though!

These questions may help:

- [glGenBuffers not defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032386/glgenbuffers-not-defined)
- [OpenGL: How to check if the user supports glGenBuffers()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317062/opengl-how-to-check-if-the-user-supports-glgenbuffers)